# Google maps street view publish

Tags: publish, google-street-view, google-streetview-publish

What is the procedure to follow for google street view publish. Is google cloud service required?

When I tried, is returned me status `Unauthorized`

I tried to find an answer here already, on StackOverflow, but all are not clear. Please guide me.

Answer (score 0):

This error means that the your access token is missing or incorrect. Make sure the http header contains a valid token like

`authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN`

You can find out more in Google's OAuth2 documentation:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2